# What super-powers does SE staff have, that diamond moderators do not have?

Tags: discussion, moderators, faq-proposed, stack-exchange-team

What super-powers do SE staff have, that diamond moderators do not?

See also:

- [Who are the diamond moderators, and what is their role?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75189/172266)
- [Differentiate between employees and moderators](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/77883/172266)

Comment: you mean all staff? or just certain staff? And do you mean actual implemented powers on the site or just stuff like "the sysadmin can make the database go poof" :)

Comment: I mean the actual implemented powers on the site. Otherwise they can do anything, having access to the source-code (:

Comment: I think most of their super powers exist outside the actual site

Comment: @Ryathal [Related](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/39827/stack-overflow-has-too-many-men)

Comment: @RobertLongson: The questions don't appear to be very closely related. The answer to that question talks about their general duties and does not mention any mod-like powers at all.

Comment: Duplicate of https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/216414/are-there-moderators-without-a-diamond/216417#216417 which is a duplicate, following the link leads eventually to: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99338/who-are-the-community-team-and-what-do-they-do - they have super powers (use Moderator Console, or dig deeper) but leave "moderation" to the moderators unless it's a beta site, pre pro-tem, then they moderate. If something can wait for the Moderator or the site's users then they should leave it, if is truly awful and purposeless vitriol then deletion is OK.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Not all employees have the same powers, they tend to have only those abilities they need for their job.

Some additional abilites that SE employees have are:

- Invalidation of votes between users
- View votes ([developers and community managers only](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/90735/can-admins-see-who-downvoted-them-if-not-do-developers-with-db-access-look-it/90758#90758), except for their own posts)
- [Permanent deletion of post revisions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86195/who-has-the-privilege-to-delete-a-revision), viewing redaction history of post revisions
- Modifying the keyword blacklist for each site
- Burninating (removing) tags
- Placing entire sites in read-only mode
- Migrating questions that are older than 60 days
- Issuing network-wide suspensions and long-term suspensions (of more than a year)
- Editing any help pages
- Editing custom close reasons (without making a new one)
- Creating post notices
- Internal SEDE with more information, particularly regarding deleted content and real time access to the site database (no 7 day wait)
- Merge user accounts.

Of course, any SE employee with database access can do far more if they want to.